# Issue with using filter within group_by from dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summary

I looked around a fair bit and tried different solutions but nothing seems to be coming to light. I am sure its an easy fix.....

I have 98 data points across 9 taxonomic classes (`Class`) in data frame `a`. Each data point has its own p.value (`p.value`) which vary in a column.

I need various bits (see below) to be done on `Class` using the `group_by` function in `dplyr`.

For my `AICorrect` column I need to count the total p.values where `p.value < 1` grouped by Class.

I have the following function

```
output <- as.data.frame(a %>%
                          group_by(Class) %>%
                          summarise(Abundance = length(Class),
                                    Density = length(Class) / h2o_m3,
                                    AICorrect = length(count(p.value < 1)) ## issue here
                                    ))
```

it is 'not having it' and reports the follow error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "logical".
```

Any insight would be great!

Thanks

(really nasty code below warning)

H20

```
h20_m3 <- 0.3424667
```

`dput` output for first 20 rows

```
structure(list(Lat = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("51  12.93257'", 
"51  12.93378'", "51  13.0399'", "51  13.20549'", "52  12.93257'", 
"52  13.20549'", "53  12.93257'", "53  13.20549'", "54  12.93257'", 
"54  13.20549'", "55  12.93257'", "55  13.20549'", "56  12.93257'", 
"56  13.20549'", "57  12.93257'", "57  13.20549'", "58  12.93257'", 
"58  13.20549'", "59  12.93257'", "59  13.20549'", "60  12.93257'", 
"60  13.20549'", "61  12.93257'", "61  13.20549'", "62  12.93257'", 
"62  13.20549'", "63  12.93257'", "63  13.20549'", "64  12.93257'", 
"64  13.20549'", "65  12.93257'", "65  13.20549'", "66  12.93257'", 
"66  13.20549'"), class = "factor"), Long = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("- 5   1.23944'", "- 5   1.23960'", "- 5   1.33092'", 
"- 5   1.36293'"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "22/11/2018", class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("03:22:40", "03:22:41", "03:22:42", "03:22:43", 
"03:22:44", "03:22:46", "03:22:47", "03:22:49", "03:22:57", "03:22:59", 
"03:23:01", "03:23:05", "03:23:06", "03:23:11", "03:23:14", "03:23:16", 
"03:23:17", "03:23:20", "03:23:21", "03:23:24", "03:23:26", "03:23:29", 
"03:23:30", "03:23:31", "03:23:32", "03:23:33", "03:23:34", "03:23:38", 
"03:23:41", "03:23:44", "03:23:46", "03:23:53", "03:23:57", "03:24:00", 
"03:24:05", "03:24:08", "03:24:13", "03:24:14", "03:24:17", "03:24:20", 
"03:24:22", "03:24:28", "03:24:30", "03:24:32", "03:24:33", "03:24:36", 
"03:24:37", "03:24:44", "03:24:47", "03:24:56", "03:25:09", "03:25:11", 
"03:25:12", "03:25:17", "03:25:21", "03:25:36", "03:25:46", "03:25:50", 
"03:25:56", "03:26:02", "03:26:07", "03:26:09", "03:26:12", "03:26:23", 
"03:26:31", "03:26:40", "03:27:03", "03:27:41", "03:27:50", "03:27:57", 
"03:28:21", "03:38:14"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(9L, 
9L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("AirBubbles", "Bryozoa_Larvae", "Chaetognath", 
"Copepod_Cyclopoid_Corycaeus_spp", "Copepod_Harpacticoid", "Detritus", 
"Doliolids", "Fish_eggs", "Krill_Nauplii", "Polychaete_larvae"
), class = "factor"), p.value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.3, 1), Area = c(4618.5, 3456.5, 1664, 
1124.5, 808, 624.5, 1188, 4905, 4098.5, 1622, 965, 5112.5, 3600.5, 
1329.5, 419.5, 1946.5, 859.5, 1461, 2101, 1808), MajAx = c(160.331, 
122.041, 48.5977, 134.161, 79.0913, 82.2169, 52, 136.107, 107.077, 
66.3892, 77.7797, 144.534, 101.12, 50.1081, 35.8204, 59.397, 
49, 71.2319, 81.2104, 69), MinAx = c(87.2272, 48.9879, 44.701, 
34.8173, 39.0966, 13.6236, 44, 78.8193, 74.0917, 52.1584, 54.5753, 
81.2652, 72.304, 38.059, 19.7893, 50.2046, 22, 43.9899, 42.3231, 
56)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `dput(a)` in your question? And is `h2o_m3` a column of the data.frame or another data.frame?

Comment: Yes I will do that but its going to be pretty nasty, there is a fair bit in there. Sorry I should have perhaps left the Density bit out, it works fine, but its just a value for your interest.

Comment: You can also just output the first 20 rows like `dput(head(a, 20))`.

Comment: Its edited, I edited a few p values in the first 20 rows so there would be a total count of 2 in total, although not sure which classes they are in.....

Comment: Thanks, now there is still `h2o_m3` missing. Could you add that too?

Comment: h20_m3 <- 0.3424667
will add in question too

Comment: `AICorrect = sum(p.value < 1, na.rm = T)`

Comment: @A. Suliman Great that worked a treat! Makes me wonder what I was doing wrong!! Thanks you, if you put as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
count(a$p.value < 1)
```

which gives this error:

> Error in UseMethod("groups") :    no applicable method for 'groups'
>   applied to an object of class "logical"

This happens because `count` calls `group_by` and `ungroup`.

You can replace `count` with `sum` to count all TRUE values.

```
output <- as.data.frame(a %>%
                          group_by(Class) %>%
                          summarise(Abundance = length(Class),
                                    Density = length(Class) / h2o_m3,
                                    AICorrect = sum(p.value < 1) ## issue here
                          ))
```